# Explanation of how symfony2 annotations work

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I am using symfony2 annotations and want to know how cascading works in this format.

Lets say I have:

```
/**
* @Route("/reviews/{slug}", name="reviewDetail")
* @Template()
*/
```

first, then I check to see if that pulls any data. If not, I do a redirect to the following controller using the following redirect:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reviewsDate', array('date' => $slug)), 301);
```

which should go to:

```
/**
* @Route("/reviews/{date}", name="reviewsDate", defaults={"date" = null})
* @Template()
*/
```

then check to see if that pulls any data and, if not, create a fallback to this using a redirect:

```
/**
* @Route("/reviews", name="reviews")
* @Template()
*/
```

When I run a redirect:

```
if ($ctx->getReview($slug)) {
  $review = $ctx->getReview($slug);
} else {
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reviewsDate', array('date' => $slug)), 301);
}
```

I get this error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

The actions are all stacked in the order of acceptance, so I would check for the slug first, then the date, then if no result, kick it to the main reviews page.

I can change the route to be more specific, which would work, but it seems not as user friendly. For instance, if I wanted to have these multiple routes:

reviews/my-review: shows the specific review
reviews/2014: shows all reviews from the 2014 year

Is this the wrong way of of executing this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
* @Route("/reviews/{date}", name="reviewsDate", defaults={"date" = null})
* @Template()
*/
```

this is this same route as

```
/**
* @Route("/reviews", name="reviews")
* @Template()
*/
```

becouse you have default value `null` for `date` parameter so if you redirect to `reviews` you are going to `reviewDate` without parameter that causes endless loop.

Comment: Got it. These cascade just as routing in a yml file correct?

Comment: I didnt understand Your question

Comment: The annotations check for the route from top to bottom, so the placement of the annotation in the controller can effect which route gets chosen.